# What happens to pthread_key_create() generated keys after a process fork?

Tags: linux, pthreads, fork, freebsd

From `pthread_key_create` FreeBSD man page:
/comment

> ... The `pthread_key_create()` function creates a thread-specific data key visible to all threads in the process.  Key values provided by `pthread_key_create()` are ***opaque*** objects used to locate thread-specific data.  Although the same key value may be used by different threads, the values bound to the key by `pthread_setspecific()` are maintained on a per-thread basis and persist for the life of the calling thread.

I am assuming that produced `pthread_key_t` instances are bound to a process (hence the ***opaque*** word in the man page), and that these become invalid after a `fork()`. I couldn't find any reference in existing man pages or documentation however.

Can anyone confirm/comment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I am assuming that produced pthread_key_t instances are bound to a process

There is every reason to think that instances are process-specific, in that if you, say, record the representation of a key in shared memory then it is not meaningful to unrelated processes that happen to map the same shared memory segment.

> (hence the opaque word in the man page),

But "opaque" has nothing in particular to do with that.  It just means that there are no user-serviceable parts inside.  You're meant to use it only as a whole.

> and that these become invalid after a fork().

That seems a bit of a jump.  I would not expect that at all.  `fork()` creates a nearly exact duplicate of the calling process, subject to a few explicitly enumerated exceptions, which are listed in [the manual](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html).  Probably the biggest relevant one is that the new process contains only one thread (the one that called `fork()`).  Invalidation of thread-specific data keys is not on the list, nor is the loss of thread-specific data of the one initial thread of the child.

> I couldn't find any reference in existing man pages or documentation however.

Exactly so.

**HOWEVER**, multi-threaded programs generally should not fork, as there is a high risk that the child process is left in an invalid state, such as with mutexes that are locked by threads that do not exist in the child.  There are a few special cases, such as forking a child that immediately `exec`s, but for the most part, you should not attempt to mix multithreading with multiprocessing.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. Thinking twice, the pthread_key_t instance might remain valid; however, any data associated with it (with the help of pthread_getspecific()) won't be, since the forked process means a different thread of execution anyway, does that make sense?

Mixing fork() and threads is not a choice, this comes as part of implementing a multithreaded library that must support forking by consuming apps.

Comment: No, @keldonin, your conclusion that the thread-specific data would not be valid in the child's one thread does not make sense.    You seem not to be grasping the significance of the child being a (nearly) exact copy of the original.  The copy of the process contains a copy of the thread-specific data, which the copy of the one thread can access via its copy of the key.

Comment: @keldonin, it is usually a far better strategy for a reusable library to be *thread-safe* than to be multi-threaded, because it is exceedingly difficult to make a meaningfully, non-trivially multi-threaded library *fork-safe*.  Do have a look at `pthread_atfork()` if you are obligated or determined to press forward with that, but do also understand that you are playing with fire.

Comment: I get your point on thread-specific data as well. Thanks as well for your advise; However the need for the library to run a parallel task remains. I could possibly make it multi-process instead, not sure however if this will be less complex. I do use the `pthread_arfork()` indeed, and I confirm it's non trivial.
Thanks,